# Encrypting connection string at client side

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, database-connection

I found topics that says that the decryption of the connection string in app.config must take place on the same machine used to encrypt it, does this mean that I should add a code that encrypt the connection string and run it on the clients PCs? (C#, VS2010, Dot net3.5, SQL Server 2008R2)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: (C#, VS2010, Dot net3.5, SQL Server 2008R2)

Comment: What is your intended end result? Why do you want to encrypt the connection string? If your client application must be able to decrypt it, so can the end user.

Comment: My main problem is : I need to protect the connection string, If I encrypt on my pc, will it work correctly on the client machine? will it be decrypted by the application so it knows to which sql and database it should connect?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by _"I need to protect the connection string"_? It's not protected from the end user running your application. If your application can decrypt it, so can the end user.

Comment: aha ! that is why I am asking ! what is the purpose of the encryption then ! (I encrypted using aspnet_regiis)